# Form data missing when I submit it using JQuery Form Plugin's "ajaxSubmit".

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

```
function QuickSave() {

        var options = {
            url: $('form[name=aspnetForm]').attr('action').split('?')[0] + "?Save=",
            success: function(t) {
            $("#<%# hdnQueryId.ClientID %>").val(t);
            $("#<%# hdnIsQuickSave.ClientID %>").val("false");
            }
        };

        $("#<%# hdnIsQuickSave.ClientID %>").val("true");
        $('form[name=aspnetForm]').ajaxSubmit(options);
    }
```

When I submit my form using `ajaxSubmit`, I do not get the values of the controls at the server side, ListBox does not have items in it, Textbox has empty text, Dropdown always has selectedIndex=0.

I have a normal `asp:buton` also on my Page and when I submit by clicking on this button, I get the proper data at the server side.

Why is this happenning. Is there some other option to be included in the code.

Please help to solve or provide any alternate implementation..

> EDIT
>   I modified my code to use $.ajax with type="post" and it worked, but then I was not getting the items in my ListBoxes (Items were added through Javascript at client side).
>
> Then I read somewhere that only selected items are serialized and sent to the server, So, I selected all items before serializing the form, and after ajax submitting, deselected all items, this started working and I was getting all Items in my ListBox at server side, But then I faced another issue:-
>
> I had two such ListBoxes on my Page and I did the same thing for both of them, but I am getting the Items in one ListBox but not in the second one.
>
> After all this, I reverted back to my previous code with "ajaxSubmit" and that started working too, but the same problem here also, getting Items in one Listbox but not in another.

Any help is much appreciated!